# Mozilla Thunderbird: Compose Messages in a New Tab

Tags: email, thunderbird, tabs, reply

Is it possible (with or without extensions) to always compose/write/reply-to messages in a new tab, as opposed to a new window, so that those open tabs will be saved (along with their contents) when you exit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449299) it's still not implemented.

> Status:   NEW
>
> Reported:     2008-08-05 16:14 PDT by Susurrus
>
> Assigned To:  Nobody; OK to take it and work on it
>
> Importance:   -- enhancement with 215 votes
>
> With Thunderbird having a tab interface, it now makes sense to have
> the compose window default to opening in a new tab versus in a new
> window. This should probably be a default option but then also have a
> separate keyboard shortcut; maybe CTRL+N could be used for new window
> like it is now and CTRL+SHIFT+N could be used for opening in a new
> tab.
>
> I really think the default should be changed to open in a new tab, but
> people don't really like change, so maybe give them the option now and
> change it in the future?

[Compose](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/thunderbird/addon/compose-for-thunderbird/) extension is abandoned.

> Attention: this addon is a proof of concept, it's experimental and
> unmaintained. Use at your own risk! We're actively looking for
> contributors to help with the development. Come and check out our
> GitHub project!
>
> This addon allows you to write message in a new messenger tab. It uses
> CKEditor, and replaces the old compose window.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Is there any update on the extension?